# In Azure Data Factory: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field of type float32

Tags: azure-data-factory

after transforming a xml to JSON and trying to post the data to an API, I get the following error:

> cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field 'xxx' of type float32.

I guessed it was a matter of data taypes, so in the source schema I tried to modify the affected field 'xxx', trying all the possible number data types (short, long, double, integer and float). But I keep getting the same error.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you add Error image and pipeline flow? and sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

> cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field

The error occurs due to **“unmarshal JSON data into a Go struct, and there’s a mismatch between the JSON data and the Go struct definition”**.

**There are multiple potential causes for this issue, including:**

- The Go struct field doesn't match the name of the corresponding JSON object property.
- The type of the Go struct field is incorrect.
- The JSON object property is missing.

**Here is come checks to avoid this error.**

- Verify that the names of the Go struct fields correspond to the names of the JSON object properties.
- Ensure that the types of the Go struct fields align with the types of the JSON object properties.
- Ensure that all necessary JSON object properties are included.
  cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field